# Columns to Rows queries

Tags: mysql, select, pivot

I have a table that look like this:

```
Company Year    Revenue Cost    Profit
ABC      1         10    6        4
ABC      2         12    7        5
ABC      3         14    8        6
XYZ      1         25   18        7
XYZ      2         27   19        8
XYZ      3         29   20        9
```

I want it look like this:

```
Company Item    1   2   3
ABC     Revenue 10  12  14
ABC     Cost    6   7   8
ABC     Profit  4   5   6
XYZ     Revenue 25  27  29
XYZ     Cost    18  19  20
XYZ     Profit  7   8   9
```

A crosstab query only allows one value.  I can do it using separate crosstab queries for Revenue, Cost And Profit and the combine using the Union function but there must be an easier way.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Max

Comment: what if it Revenue, cost and profit have more than 10 rows for a company?

Comment: This is very likely.. will have 20 row per company. Other items will be overheads, Marketing, etcThx

Comment: What about changing table structure instead of one have `one to many relationship`?

Comment: Generally, it's best to handle issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code (e.g. a simple PHP loop on an ordered array)

Comment: The above data is derived from a query so a one to many relationship does not apple.

Comment: Stawberry, like your idea of a loop.  Do you have a simple example I can follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reasons of scalability (and flexibility), problems like this are best left to the application level code (e.g. a simple PHP loop on a well-ordered result set) but, just for fun...

```
SELECT company
     , item
     , MAX(CASE WHEN year = 1 THEN value END) y1
     , MAX(CASE WHEN year = 2 THEN value END) y2
     , MAX(CASE WHEN year = 3 THEN value END) y3
  FROM 
     ( SELECT company, year, 'revenue' item, revenue value FROM my_table
       UNION
       SELECT company, year, 'cost',cost FROM my_table
       UNION
       SELECT company, year, 'profit',profit FROM my_table
     ) x
 GROUP
    BY company
     , item
 ORDER 
    BY company
     , FIELD(item,'Revenue','Cost','Profit');
```

Answer (score 2):

Variation for you to try.

```
SELECT Company, 
    item, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(item_details, ',', 1), ',', -1) AS `1`,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(item_details, ',', 2), ',', -1) AS `2`,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(item_details, ',', 3), ',', -1) AS `3`
FROM
(
    SELECT Company, 'Revenue' AS item, GROUP_CONCAT(Revenue ORDER BY `Year`) AS item_details
    FROM SomeTable
    GROUP BY Company
    UNION
    SELECT Company, 'Cost' AS item, GROUP_CONCAT(Cost ORDER BY `Year`)
    FROM SomeTable
    GROUP BY Company
    UNION
    SELECT Company, 'Profit' AS item, GROUP_CONCAT(Profit ORDER BY `Year`)
    FROM SomeTable
    GROUP BY Company
) Sub1
ORDER BY Company, FIELD(Item, 'Revenue', 'Cost', 'Profit')
```

SQL fiddle for you:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/995a0/6

Comment: Kickstart, like your elegant solution but pls bear with this newbie.  Pasted your code into my query and changed to my table name.  Get error "syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'GROUP_CONCAT(Revenue ORDER BY `Year`)'. Thx

Comment: I can't see anything obvious. Can you paste the full query (possible the error is elsewhere in the query). As the sqlfiddle shows it should work as it is.

Comment: SELECT Company AS Expr1, item AS Expr2, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(item_details,',',1),',',-1) AS 1, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(item_details,',',2),',',-1) AS 2, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(item_details,',',3),',',-1) AS 3
FROM (SELECT Company, 'Revenue' AS item, GROUP_CONCAT(Revenue ORDER BY `Year`) AS item_details

Comment: FROM TableA
    GROUP BY Company
    UNION
    SELECT Company, 'Cost' AS item, GROUP_CONCAT(Cost ORDER BY `Year`)
    FROM TableA
    GROUP BY Company
    UNION
    SELECT Company, 'Profit' AS item, GROUP_CONCAT(Profit ORDER BY `Year`) 
    FROM TableA
    GROUP BY Company
)  AS Sub1
ORDER BY Company, FIELD(Item,'Revenue','Cost','Profit');

Comment: The column names for the years I have just called 1, 2 and 3. However for these to be column names they need back tics around them. Without the back tics you get an error but with them the SQL seems to work. Updated the SQL fiddle to test - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02fd5/2

Comment: Output on sqlfiddle link is perfect. I am getting the same error. I am using MS Access if than makes a difference.

Comment: That makes a massive difference as Access has a very poor and non standard implementation of SQL. Afraid I don't think it has an equivalent of the MySQL function GROUP_CONCAT.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Company, Item, Col1 AS 1, Col2 AS 2, Col3 AS 3
FROM (SELECT a.Company, 'Revenue' AS Item, MAX(IF(a.Year = 1, a.Revenue, 0)) AS Col1, 
             MAX(IF(a.Year = 2, a.Revenue, 0)) AS Col2, MAX(IF(a.Year = 3, a.Revenue, 0)) AS Col3
      FROM tableA a 
      GROUP BY a.Company 
      UNION 
      SELECT a.Company, 'Cost' AS Item, MAX(IF(a.Year = 1, a.Cost, 0)) AS Col1, 
             MAX(IF(a.Year = 2, a.Cost, 0)) AS Col2, MAX(IF(a.Year = 3, a.Cost, 0)) AS Col3
      FROM tableA a 
      GROUP BY a.Company 
      UNION
      SELECT a.Company, 'Profit' AS Item, MAX(IF(a.Year = 1, a.Profit, 0)) AS Col1, 
             MAX(IF(a.Year = 2, a.Profit, 0)) AS Col2, MAX(IF(a.Year = 3, a.Profit, 0)) AS Col3
      FROM tableA a 
      GROUP BY a.Company 
     ) AS A 
ORDER BY Company, FIELD(Item, 'Revenue', 'Cost', 'Profit')
```

Comment: Great!  works fine after adjusting IF and field statements.  One more question - I have 20 years of data.  Is there an easier way of writing the MAX statement

Answer (score 0):

A second way of doing it. Not tested (so probably some typos), but doing some SQL to get the data then looping around the details, lobbing them to an object to put out the rows. This will cope with any where a company is missing a data for a year.

Note that you could greatly simplify the SQL if you had a table of years that you are interested in and a table of companies.

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT Sub1.Year, Sub2.Company, IFNULL(SomeTable.Revenue, 0) AS aValue, 'Revenue' AS Item
        FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT Year FROM SomeTable
        ) Sub1
        CROSS JOIN 
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT Company FROM SomeTable
        ) Sub2
        LEFT OUTER JOIN SomeTable
        ON Sub1.Year = SomeTable.Year
        AND Sub2.Company = SomeTable.Company
        UNION
        SELECT Sub1.Year, Sub2.Company, IFNULL(SomeTable.Cost, 0) AS aValue, 'Cost' AS Item
        FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT Year FROM SomeTable
        ) Sub1
        CROSS JOIN 
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT Company FROM SomeTable
        ) Sub2
        LEFT OUTER JOIN SomeTable
        ON Sub1.Year = SomeTable.Year
        AND Sub2.Company = SomeTable.Company
        UNION
        SELECT Sub1.Year, Sub2.Company, IFNULL(SomeTable.Profit, 0) AS aValue, 'Profit' AS Item
        FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT Year FROM SomeTable
        ) Sub1
        CROSS JOIN 
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT Company FROM SomeTable
        ) Sub2
        LEFT OUTER JOIN SomeTable
        ON Sub1.Year = SomeTable.Year
        AND Sub2.Company = SomeTable.Company
        ORDER BY Company, FIELD(Item, 'Revenue', 'Cost', 'Profit'), Year";

$query = $db->query($sql) or die($db->error()) ;
if ($row = $this->db->fetchAssoc())
{
    echo "<table>";
    $PrevCompany = $row['Company'];
    $PrevItem = $row['Item'];
    $aLine = new ProcessLine($PrevCompany, $PrevItem, true);
    do
    {
        if ($PrevCompany != $row['Company'] or $PrevItem != $row['Item'])
        {
            unset($aLine);
            $PrevCompany = $row['Company'];
            $PrevItem = $row['Item'];
            $aLine = new ProcessLine($PrevCompany, $PrevItem);
        }
        $aLine->Assign_Detail($row['Year'], $row['aValue'])

    } while($row = $this->db->fetchAssoc());
    unset($aLine);
    echo "</table>";
}

class ProcessLine
{
    private $Company;
    private $Item;
    private $row_details = array();
    private $FirstRow = false
    public __CONSTRUCT($Company, $Item, $FirstRow=false)
    {
        $this->Company = $Company;
        $this->Item = $Item;
    }

    public __DESTRUCT()
    {
        if ($this->Firstrow)
        {
            echo "<tr><th>".$this->Company."</th><th>".$this->Item."</th>";
            foreach($row_details AS $row_year=>$row_value)
            {
                echo "<th>$row_year</th>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "<tr><td>".$this->Company."</td><td>".$this->Item."</td><td>".implode("</td><td>", $row_details)."</td></tr>";
    }

    public Assign_Detail($in_year, $in_value)
    {
        $row_details[$in_year] = $in_value;
    }
}

?>
```